# class error Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php

I have the following class and its not accepting $this keyword in the method.
can someone guid

```
<?php
class test {

    function __construct($x, $y, $z){

        $this->$x = $x;


        $this->testFunction();





public static function testFunction(){



    print '<br> here it is:'.$this->$x.'--<br>';
}



//========================================================================================================================
}
?>
```

it gives me this error

```
 Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but is the missing closing } on the constructor a typo? If it is not, that needs to be closed.

Comment: Please re-format your code becouse it seems a } is missing. @ Stewie, that's another error, it doesn't really caused the fatal error.

Comment: ah ! I was thinking of "self" and I wrote "this" .. Lacking caffeine this morning :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a static function, you need to use `self`:

```
print '<br> here it is:'.self::$x.'--<br>';
```

`$this` refers to an object instance, which does not exist in a static context.

That said, in a static context, the constructor will never have been called so `$x` will always be empty. I'm not sure whether `public static function` is really what you want here.

**Edit:** Additionally, as @netcoder points out, `$x` needs to be declared a static member as well.

Comment: $x needs to be declared as a static member, otherwise it will trigger a fatal error when referencing `self::$x`.

Comment: For as long as I can remember.

Comment: @netcoder ah, what do you know. You're right. I stand corrected

Answer (score 2):

Your method is static, you can't use $this in static context. You have to use *self*, but it will trigger a Fatal error because $x is not declared as a static member.

This will work:

```
class test {

   static protected $x = 'hello world';

   static public function testFunction() {
      echo self::$x;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are using the keyword $this outside the class.
There are a lot of syntax errors here:

1 - a `}` is missing probably in the first function.
2 - i think that not using one of the `public`, `protected`, `private` keyword in a class's function declaration is a mistake.
3 - To call a variable you have to use the `$this->var_name` syntax, while using a constant you should use the `self::cons_name`.

Comment: Why never? Using `$` after `::` is mandatory to access static properties. Also, using `$this->$x` is useful for accessing object properties dynamically.